# How to get the child nodes of a particular account in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Hi guys i want to retrieve the child nodes of a particular account in sales force.How do i achieve this? 
I am not very much aware of the data model that sales force use. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming you're using SOQL to retrive the child data. If I'm wrong please clarify.

This will depend on the relationship you're trying to access but in general you can do a query like this to select the child elements of a Parent

SELECT id, name, (SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account where Name = 'Acme'

Full details of the SOQL query language are here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Salesforce API then you can use describeSObjects() to retrieve metadata about any object you are interested in, including the Account object.

The syntax is:

```
DescribeSObjectResult [] = sfdc.describeSObjects(string sObjectType[] );
```

Where sObjectType is an array of up to 100 objects.

To describe an account, use:

```
DescribeSObjectResult [] = sfdc.describeSObjects("account");
```

The DescribeSObjectResult array has many properties that can be used to discover information about the object. For example, if you want a list of the fields belonging to the account object, you would use DescribeSObjectResult.Fields.

Here is some sample Java code from the [Salesforce API Developer's Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api90/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm#topic-title). This should help you get started. There are also C# samples if you follow the link to the developers reference.

```
private void describeSObjectsSample()
{
  try {
    DescribeSObjectResult[] describeSObjectResults =
      binding.describeSObjects(new String[] {"account", "contact", "lead"});
    for (int x=0;x<describeSObjectResults.length;x++)
    {
      DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResult = describeSObjectResults[x];
      // Retrieve fields from the results
      Field[] fields = describeSObjectResult.getFields();
      // Get the name of the object
      String objectName = describeSObjectResult.getName();
      // Get some flags
      boolean isActivateable = describeSObjectResult.isActivateable();
      System.out.println("Object name: " + objectName);
      // Many other values are accessible
      if (fields != null)
      {
        // Iterate through the fields to get properties for each field
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
          Field field = fields[i];
          int byteLength = field.getByteLength();
          int digits = field.getDigits();
          String label = field.getLabel();
          int length = field.getLength();
          String name = field.getName();
          PicklistEntry[] picklistValues = field.getPicklistValues();
          int precision = field.getPrecision();
          String[] referenceTos = field.getReferenceTo();
          int scale = field.getScale();
          FieldType fieldType = field.getType();
          boolean fieldIsCreateable = field.isCreateable();
          System.out.println("Field name: " + name);
          // Determine whether there are picklist values
          if (picklistValues != null && picklistValues[0] != null)
          {
            System.out.println("Picklist values = ");
            for (int j = 0; j < picklistValues.length; j++)
            {
              if (picklistValues[j].getLabel() != null)
              {
                System.out.println(" Item: " +
                    picklistValues[j].getLabel());
              }
            }
          }
          // Determine whether this field refers to another object
          if (referenceTos != null && referenceTos[0] != null)
          {
            System.out.println("Field references the following objects:");
            for (int j = 0; j < referenceTos.length; j++)
            {
              System.out.println(" " + referenceTos[j]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("\nFailed to get object descriptions, error message was: \n" + 
                       ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```